# SQL Help : How to produce data output from multiple tables that need to be summed and find out the MAX date?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

In order to produce "Production Report" I need to join many tables together and find out sum of product line's qty that was produced in each lot and what is the latest activity that each line produced.

I can sum data and find out the MAX activity in separate SQL query, but when i joined them, the query show error. So could you please help me. Thank you very much.

My tables are below :

```
tbl_pdtn_startup
pdtn_st_id | pd_id | pdtn_st_date
   3       |  001  |  3/9/12
   4       |  002  |  4/9/12

tbl_pdtn_sizecolor
pdtn_szcl_id | pdtn_st_id | pdtn_st_color | pdtn_st_size | pdtn_st_qty_est
    23       |    3       |   Blue        |    S         |    100
    26       |    3       |   Pink        |    S         |    100
    27       |    3       |   Green       |    S         |    100
    28       |    4       |   Blue        |    M         |    200
    30       |    4       |   Green       |    M         |    200


tbl_production
pdtn_id | pdtn_szcl_id | pdtn_st_id | pdtn_date | pd_making_id | lb_id
  24    |     23       |    3       |   4/9/12  |    1         |  12
  26    |     23       |    3       |   5/9/12  |    2         |  12
  27    |     26       |    3       |   4/9/12  |    1         |  15
  28    |     27       |    3       |   5/9/12  |    1         |  15 <--MAX(pdtn_date)
  29    |     28       |    4       |   4/9/12  |    4         |  15
  30    |     30       |    4       |   6/9/12  |    5         |  12 <--MAX(pdtn_date)

tbl_product
  pd_id | Name
   001  | product A
   002  | product B

tbl_pdWk_process
 pd_making_id | wk_stage | pd_id | cost
     1        | step 1   |  001  |  12
     2        | step 2   |  001  |  15
     3        | step 1   |  003  |  12
     4        | step 1   |  002  |  18
     5        | step 2   |  002  |  10

tbl_labor
lb_id | lb_name
 12   | john
 15   | Mary
```

I need the output as show below :

```
pd_id | pd_name  | pdtn_st_date | sum(pdtn_st_qty_est)*|MAX(pdtn_date)**| wk_stage | lb_name
 001  | product A|   3/9/12     |   300                |   5/9/12       |  step 1  |  Mary
 002  | product B|   4/9/12     |   400                |   6/9/12       |  step 2  | John
```

Note
* Sum(pdtn_st_qty_est) comes from sum of all pdtn_st_qty_est in the same pdtn_st_id (production_startup_id) (for ex:- Blue=100, Pink=100, Green=100 for pdtn_st_id = 3) 
** MAX(pdtn_date) comes from the latest activity that worker has been done for each product lot(for ex:- 5/9/12 from pdtn_st_id = 3 )

Below was my attempt that tried to join the 3 mains table together but fail..

```
SELECT U.pd_id,  A.SumOfpdtn_st_qty_est, S.MaxOfpdtn_date
FROM (tbl_pdtn_startup AS U INNER JOIN 
    [SELECT  Sum(tbl_pdtn_sizecolor.pdtn_st_qty_est) AS SumOfpdtn_st_qty_est FROM tbl_pdtn_sizecolor GROUP BY tbl_pdtn_sizecolor.pdtn_st_id]. AS A ON U.pdtn_st_id = A.pdtn_st_id) 
         INNER JOIN 
        [SELECT Max(tbl_production.pdtn_date) AS MaxOfpdtn_date FROM tbl_production GROUP BY tbl_production.pdtn_st_id]. AS S ON (A.pdtn_szcl_id = S.pdtn_szcl_id) AND (U.pdtn_st_id = S.pdtn_st_id)
```

**My next attempt:**
I've came up with the idea of making separate query and join them together, which it can produce partial data that i want. Now there's only 2 data that i couldn't retrieve it right. which are lb_name and wk_stage. So could anybody help me. Thank you very much.

q_maxdate

```
SELECT tbl_pdtn_startup.pdtn_st_id, tbl_pdtn_startup.pd_id, Max(tbl_production.pdtn_date) AS MaxOfpdtn_date, tbl_product.pd_name, tbl_pdtn_startup.pdtn_st_pdNote, tbl_pdtn_startup.pdtn_st_date
FROM (((tbl_pdtn_startup INNER JOIN tbl_pdtn_sizecolor ON tbl_pdtn_startup.pdtn_st_id=tbl_pdtn_sizecolor.pdtn_st_id) INNER JOIN tbl_production ON tbl_pdtn_sizecolor.pdtn_szcl_id=tbl_production.pdtn_szcl_id) INNER JOIN tbl_product ON tbl_pdtn_startup.pd_id=tbl_product.pd_id) INNER JOIN tbl_pdWk_process ON (tbl_production.pd_making_id=tbl_pdWk_process.pd_making_id) AND (tbl_product.pd_id=tbl_pdWk_process.pd_id)
GROUP BY tbl_pdtn_startup.pdtn_st_id, tbl_pdtn_startup.pd_id, tbl_product.pd_name, tbl_pdtn_startup.pdtn_st_pdNote, tbl_pdtn_startup.pdtn_st_date;
```

then i joined it in this query...

```
SELECT q_maxdate.pdtn_st_id, Sum(tbl_pdtn_sizecolor.pdtn_st_qty_est) AS SumOfpdtn_st_qty_est, q_maxdate.MaxOfpdtn_date, q_maxdate.pd_name, q_maxdate.pdtn_st_pdNote, q_maxdate.pd_id, q_maxdate.pdtn_st_date
FROM q_maxdate INNER JOIN tbl_pdtn_sizecolor ON q_maxdate.pdtn_st_id = tbl_pdtn_sizecolor.pdtn_st_id
GROUP BY q_maxdate.pdtn_st_id, q_maxdate.MaxOfpdtn_date, q_maxdate.pd_name, q_maxdate.pdtn_st_pdNote, q_maxdate.pd_id, q_maxdate.pdtn_st_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is sample SQL. Your labour names do not seem to match your sample data.

```
SELECT tbl_pdtn_startup.pd_id,
       tbl_product.name,
       tbl_pdtn_startup.pdtn_st_date,
       tbl_pdwk_process.wk_stage,
       tbl_labor.lb_name,
       SUM(tbl_pdtn_sizecolor.pdtn_st_qty_est) AS SumOfpdtn_st_qty_est,
       Max(tbl_production.pdtn_date)           AS MaxOfpdtn_date
FROM   (((tbl_production
          INNER JOIN tbl_labor
                  ON tbl_production.lb_id = tbl_labor.lb_id)
         INNER JOIN (tbl_pdtn_sizecolor
                     INNER JOIN tbl_pdtn_startup
                             ON tbl_pdtn_sizecolor.pdtn_st_id =
                                tbl_pdtn_startup.pdtn_st_id)
                 ON tbl_production.pdtn_szcl_id =
                    tbl_pdtn_sizecolor.pdtn_szcl_id)
        INNER JOIN tbl_pdwk_process
                ON tbl_production.pd_making_id = tbl_pdwk_process.pd_making_id)
       INNER JOIN tbl_product
               ON tbl_pdtn_startup.pd_id = tbl_product.pd_id
GROUP  BY tbl_pdtn_startup.pd_id,
          tbl_product.name,
          tbl_pdtn_startup.pdtn_st_date,
          tbl_pdwk_process.wk_stage,
          tbl_labor.lb_name;
```

Comment: sorry, i've tried but it didn't work. Anyway, my labor name output seem right.. the lastest person from MaxOfpdtn_date for pdtn_st_id=3 was Mary. and production(4) was John.

Comment: Max of pdtn_date for pdtn_st_id=3 is 5/9/12 and that date occurs twice, once for John ( row 26 ) and once for Mary ( row 28 ).

Comment: i see... thank you.. this is the situation that I actually haven't thought about. So the idea of displaying each latest work process and labor name of each production lot was impossible then.

Comment: No necessarily, it all depends on how you define "latest", for example, is Max(pdtn_id) for pdtn_st_id a good definition?